# How to process batch records in Polled Consumer(PollableMessageSource )?

Tags: apache-kafka, batch-processing, spring-cloud-stream

I am using PolledConsumer with spring cloud stream.
My consumer looks like this:

```
@Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(PollableMessageSource input, MessageChannel output) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println("Send some messages to topic polledConsumerIn and receive from polledConsumerOut");
            System.out.println("Messages will be processed one per second");
            exec.execute(() -> {
                boolean result = false;
                while (true) {
                    // this is where we poll for a message, process it, and send a new one
                    result = input.poll(m -> {
                        String payload = (String) m.getPayload();
                        System.out.println("Received: " + payload);
                        output.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload.toUpperCase())
                            .copyHeaders(m.getHeaders())
                            .build());
                    }, new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>() { });

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1_000);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        break;
                    }
                    if (result) {
                        System.out.println("Success");
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    }
```

I am trying to consume records in batch mode and my aim is to get List of records after poll since my methods are batch processing.
In the code input.poll method takes MessageHandler, which takes a single record as a parameter.
After I set configuration like this:
bindings:
person:
consumer:
batch-mode: true

```
   binder:
       configuration:
         max.poll.records: 1500
         fetch.min.bytes: 900000
         fetch.max.wait.ms: 5000
         value.deserializer: tr.PersonDeserializer
```

still the result is the same.

Is there any way I can process List of records in MessageHandler meaning that the type of m.getPayload is List<> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no support for batch consumption in the polled consumer.